# LINQ: Select * from Joined Tables then Evaluate them in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following LINQ statement which compiles and works:

```
 var X= (from r in DBTableR
         join t in DBTableT on r.TID equals t.ID
         join u in DBTableU on r.UID equals u.ID
         select new { r, t, u }).ToList();
repeater1.DataSource = X;
repeater1.DataBind();
```

Now since the format of the query would look something like X.Object1.r or X.Object1.u

how can evaluate this from the asp.net code? (similar to the TEXT field in the following label)

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text=**<%# Eval() %>**></asp:Label>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it like this:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("r.YourProperty") %>'></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("t.YourProperty") %>'></asp:Label>
```

and so on..

Here, `YourProperty` will be the property within the `r,t,u` objects that you want to bind with respective controls.

Just for example, Consider this object I have binded to repeater control and its markup code:-

```
var result = from e in emp1
             join d in deps
             on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
             select new { e, d };
rptTest.DataSource = result;
rptTest.DataBind();
```

Here is the MarkUp code:-

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("e.EmployeeID") %>'></asp:Label>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("d.DeptName") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```